# Can I connect my router wirelessly to Uverse?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-router

I just switched to AT&T Uverse and my old setup (physical connection to cable modem in same room) is no longer applicable.  I want to have my home office router talk to my AT&T Uverse router in another room via wireless connection.  Can this be done?

Here is my setup:
AT&T Uverse router downstairs in kitchen (only phone port in house)
Home office upstairs accross the house. Equipement consists of 3 desktop computers & 2 older Linksys routers (E2000 is the newest one, the other is one of the old blue wireless ones)

*Limitations*:

1. Physical connections are not a possibility due to distance between routers
2. I have a gameroom in another room which will also require it's own wireless connection.  This doesn't require a separate answer, it just limits the main answer to exclude saying "plug wireless NICs into the desktops."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the DD-WRT firmware on your E2000, you can use "client" mode, which means the router will act much like a computer and connect to the other router.
Be warned, as the tutorial says: you can ruin the router if you don't follow the directions!

http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E2000

Here's info on client mode:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless

TIP: keep both routers on different channels to reduce cross-talk.

Comment: I've tried this on another (older) router before, but it "hung" during the process eventually forcing me to hard boot it several hours later, and something must have "broke" because it never worked after that. (as directions said if you didnt follow directions and that forced boot happened before I was supposed to reboot it)

Comment: +1 I think this is what I need. My understanding is that once this is done it will forever be a "wired" router as far as clients are concerned. correct?

Comment: You mean the clients on the E2000? Yes essentially.

Comment: Both answers are great. Ultimately "accepted" this answer because it uses the equipment I listed.  Still not sure which way I'm gonna try because they both look good.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider a connection via [powerline ethernet](http://www.newegg.com/Powerline-Networking/SubCategory/ID-294)? With such a solution you could use the existing powerline wiring of your house to connect your 2 routers. The performance might not be great, but it should be enough for internet and probably better than a wireless solution.

Comment: I've never used this setup, but my understanding of it was that it could receive interference if you have a lot of electrical equipment plugged in. (I do).  The term "Home Office" may have been slightly misleading since these computers are used for a LOT of gaming as well.  Wireless worked fine for them in the past but I'm not sure that they would handle the interference well.

Comment: I would not connect a server with it but for internet its fine. Newer models handle the interference quiet well. I use it myself to connect my mediacenter to the internet over a distance of 30m (100ft)

Comment: +1 this is looking even better now.  Can this be used with a router instead of directly from the PCs?  The ones I'm looking at keep saying compatible with Windows only (which I run), but I would prefer to connect them via the router instead of directly to the PC if possible.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I use Devolo dLAN 500 AVplus to connect my router with my mediacenter. The connection goes: router - devolo - powerline - devolo - mediacenter. It works with any kind of device but for the setup of security settings you need a windows computer.

Comment: Simon, I like this answer & it was hard to choose which one to "give credit" to but ultimately I went with @Bort answer because it used the equipment I listed.  Still not sure which one I'm gonna go with but I thought it was fair to let you know. Thanks for the info. (I did +1 your original answer)